# How to use Linked List to find next and previous objects in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Assume a Q & A site. When opening a question at end point `/q/<id2>`, it should also provide links to next `/q/<id1>`, previous questions `/q/<id3>`. Assuming that the table is in the order of pk values or timestamp.

This could be simply solved by creating a method like below which I'm using now:

```
def next_q(self):
    # Ques model contain all questions
    # this method is a model method of Ques
    all_q = Ques.objects.all()
    q = None
    count = 1
    if count < all_q.count():
        try:
            q = all_q.get(pk=self.pk + count)
            break
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            count += 1
    return q
```

However, I think this kind of operation is costly enough that it queries all questions (`Ques` objects) whenever a question `/q/id` is requested.

One possible way I see is to use the idea of linked list where the next & previous objects id's could be stored in current object.

There could be two fields in `Ques` Model as such

```
class Ques(models.Model):
    prev_q_id = models.IntegerField()
    next_q_id = models.IntegerField()
```

These are updated whenever a new Ques object is created, edited, deleted. This ensures that I would only query for one single object. However is I'm wondering whether it is a good approach or not. If not how else I can do?

Answer (score 5):

Using a linked list on an ordered structure is meaningless, because your database already offer you an ordered record list an d you can reach any item you want by ordering your data according to your needs.

Here is an approach that will return you what you want

```python
class Ques(Model):
    ....

    @classmethod
    def get_next(cls, current_id):  # current_id is the id of current record
        try:
            return cls.objects.filter(id__gt=current_id).order_by("id")[0]
       except:
            return None

    @classmethod
    def get_previous(cls, current_id):
        try:
            return cls.objects.filter(id__lt=current_id).order_by("-id")[0]
        except:
            return None
```

Using [classmethod](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod) is more useful in here, You simply get the next or previous closest record. If there is no record, then you get `None`

Answer (score 0):

The approach with a linked list is viable, but you do not need to change your data model to support what you want. Instead you can simply create open a cursor for all questions greater than the primary key and read the first.

Remember that objects.all() does not actually read all objects. It will simply create a cursor to the data. You can see a cursor as the database's "action plan" on how to retrieve the data. It is only when you actually fetch the data that it will start reading database records.

What you want is basically this in sql.

```
select * from Question where pk > question.pk order by pk
```

In django this would be something like

```
all_q = Ques.objects.all()
all_q.filter(pk__gt=question.pk)
all_q.order_by('pk')  # not really necessary as this is done implicitly
next_q = all_q.first()
```

For the previous record you can do the same, but use a reversed order or simply call "last" instead of first.